# Ansible: add attachment to email only if a condition is met

Tags: ansible

I am managing an ansible playbook written by third parts.
The playbook sends a mail at the end of the execution.

I want to attach a file to the mail only if this condition is met:

```
Number_of_lines_in_attachment.stdout|int > 0
```

The task I have written is the following one:

```
- name: Send the analysis via e-mail 
  community.general.mail:

    subtype: html  
    host: smtp.myserver.it
    port: 25
    sender: automated-sender@myserver.it
    to:
      "{{ mail_to_recipients }}"
    cc:
      "{{ mail_cc_recipients }}"


    subject: "[automated-sender] my analysis"
    attach:
      - "{{ attachment_path if Number_of_lines_in_attachment.stdout|int > 0 else '' }}"

    body: "{{ body_analysis }}"
```

I supposed that when the condition was not met, the value passed to the `attach` key would have been a void list, so "attach nothing"

However, this values turns out to be `''`, so it raises the error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

localhost failed | msg: Failed to send community.general.mail: can't attach file : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

So, how to change the task so that the file is attached only if the condition is met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the [`ternary`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ternary_filter.html) filter:

```yaml
- name: Send the analysis via e-mail 
  community.general.mail:
    subtype: html  
    host: smtp.myserver.it
    port: 25
    sender: automated-sender@myserver.it
    to: "{{ mail_to_recipients }}"
    cc: "{{ mail_cc_recipients }}"
    subject: "[automated-sender] my analysis"
    attach: "{{ Number_of_lines_in_attachment.stdout | int > 0 | ternary([attachment_path], omit) }}"
    body: "{{ body_analysis }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by changing

```
attach:
  - "{{ attachment_path if Number_of_lines_in_attachment.stdout|int > 0 else '' }}"
```

to

```
attach:
      "{{ [ attachment_path ] if Number_of_lines_in_attachment.stdout|int > 0 else [] }}"
```

Comment: You could also have done `attach: "{{ [ attachment_path ] if Number_of_lines_in_attachment.stdout|int > 0 else omit }}"`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks! If you want to type it as answer I will be happy to flag it as correct.