# Ansible: add many attachments to email only if a respective condition for each attachment is met

Tags: list, ansible, jinja2

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77908175/ansible-add-attachment-to-email-only-if-a-condition-is-met) it is explained how to add a single attachment to a mail sent via [community.general.mail module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/mail_module.html) only if a condition is met.

Now I would like to add as attachment many files from a list of attachments if some (="their") respective condition is met.

I have tried to do so by defining the list of files to attach is

```
list_of_attachments_paths: 
  "{% set attachments_list = [] %}
  {% if NOL_in_file1.stdout|int > 0  %}
  {{ attachments_list.append( file1_path ) }}
  {% endif %}
  {% if NOL_in_file2.stdout|int > 0  %}
  {{ attachments_list.append( file2_path ) }}
  {% endif %}
  {{ attachments_list }}"
```

a debug task

```
    - name: show list_of_attachments_paths
      debug:
        msg: 
          - "{{ list_of_attachments_paths }}"
```

and this the task to send the mail

```
- name: Send the analysis via e-mail 
  community.general.mail:

    subtype: html  
    host: smtp.myserver.it
    port: 25
    sender: automated-sender@myserver.it
    to:
      "{{ mail_to_recipients }}"
    cc:
      "{{ mail_cc_recipients }}"


    subject: "[automated-sender] my analysis"
    attach:
      - "{{ list_of_attachments_paths }}"

    body: "{{ body_analysis }}"
```

the debug task returns:

```
show list_of_attachments_paths...   
  localhost ok: {    
    "changed": false,    
    "msg": [    
        "       ['/home/myuser/mypath/file1.csv', '/home/myuser/mypath/file2.csv']"

    ]

}
```

but I get this error and I don't understand why

```
Send the report via e-mail...

An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "       ['/home/myuser/mypath/file1.csv'"

  localhost failed | msg: Failed to send community.general.mail: can't attach file        ['/home/myuser/mypath/file1.csv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "       ['/home/myuser/mypath/file1.csv'"
```

on [ansible documentation for task key `attach`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/mail_module.html#parameter-attach) it is clearly stated that the input must be a list of path of attachments, so what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a (very bad) way to solve the problem:

```
    - name: Generate void list of attachment paths
      set_fact:
        list_of_attachments_paths: "{{ [] }}"


    - name: Update list of attachment paths - file1
      when: NOL_in_file1.stdout|int > 0
      set_fact:
        list_of_attachments_paths: "{{ list_of_attachments_paths + [file1_path]  }}"


    - name: Update list of attachment paths - file2
      when: NOL_in_file2.stdout|int > 0
      set_fact:
        list_of_attachments_paths: "{{ list_of_attachments_paths + [file2_path]  }}"
```

and then

```
- name: Send the analysis via e-mail 
  community.general.mail:

    subtype: html  
    host: smtp.myserver.it
    port: 25
    sender: automated-sender@myserver.it
    to:
      "{{ mail_to_recipients }}"
    cc:
      "{{ mail_cc_recipients }}"


    subject: "[automated-sender] my analysis"
    attach:
      "{{ list_of_attachments_paths | select('defined') | list }}"  # note the select('defined) filter

    body: "{{ body_analysis }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I get this error and I don't understand why

> it is clearly stated that the input must be a list of path of attachments, so what is the problem here?

Your `list_of_attachments_paths` is not a list but rather a string that contains a string representation of a list. Moreover, you're then using it as `- "{{ list_of_attachments_paths }}"` which basically becomes a list of invalid paths.

In my opinion, you should reconsider the way you collect the attachments as your current approach is not scalable. But without knowing what inputs do you have and how do you set the variables like `NOL_in_file1`, it is impossible to give a proper recommendation.